# How to deploy Asp.net Core on a Windows 10 IoT device?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment

I created an ASP.net Core web application in Visual Studio 2015, and thought I would see the Work In Progress in action.

The action is to take place on my Raspberry Pi 3, running Windows 10 IoT, accessable on `192.168.1.200:8080` (through my browser).

However, when I attempts to deploy to it through Visual Studio, I get an error:

[image]

> Could not connect to the remote computer ("192.168.1.200"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Mangement Service") is started.

So I checked if the `Web Management Service` was running:

[image]

It is.

Then I tried to add the port:

[image]

> Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://*:8080/msdeploy.axd?site=MySite'. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Well, it tries to connect to a `https` connection, which means certificate... *Do I need that?*
If I do, I think [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) would be what I need...

Do you have any suggestions to what might be wrong?

Comment: Web Deploy isn't part of what's included with Windows 10 IoT edition. Windows 10 IoT is for running Universal Apps, not arbitrary executables, and doesn't include a web server for your use. You would probably have better luck deploying to some Linux based OS running on your device.

Comment: Alternatively, do a web search. I found a few tutorials just a Google search away. You'll have to obtain the appropriate ARM packages via PowerShell and run the site as a self hosting app instead of putting it inside IIS.

Answer (score 0):

this is not really the primary focus of the iot-core at the moment, but it is possible ([see here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2087172.aspx?ASP%20NET%20WebAPI%20MVC%20app%20to%20run%20on%20Windows%20IoT%20Core%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi))  Normally, you deploy a UWP app from VisualStudio 2015 or create it as a UWP package from Visual Studio 2015 and deploy the package. This app can use any of the azure services and the local display (if headed) but does not require a web server. [Here are plenty of samples, in particular one that installs a node.js web-server to serve http pages to clients if you need that.](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/blob/develop/WeatherStation) Personally, I prefer sending my data to the cloud and serving the web from there...